# Turn all links on a page into https within firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-3

Lets just say that I wanted to be extra careful with the website I'm visiting (irrespective of whether the site is offered in https) and wanted to convert every href in the web page received into its https equivalent.

Is there a way/add-on to do this ? or do I have to write my own :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul said, most sites will break if you do this. However, if you wanted to do something similar to this (grabbing all the links on a page and doing something to them), a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) script would be easier and quicker than writing a Firefox add-on.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction... Its baked and ready to use : http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/29090

Answer (score 0):

You can't just point all links to https, most of them will break, and secure sites will redirect you to https anyway.

Comment: actually, I would use this add-on for some specific sites i have in mind. Take for example, gmail or scribd.. gmail is no problem once the initial url is in https, but scribd doesn't work well (even though it can)...